# XMLHttpRespone is empty and status 0

Tags: javascript, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to parse XML document from java script with the below code

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {

        if (this.responseXML != null) {
            Caption(this.video, this.responseXML);
        } else {
            throw new Error("Can't read resource");
        }

    };
    xhr.video = obj;

    xhr.open("GET", "Br001.xml", true);
    xhr.send("");
```

But I am getting `status=0` and `responseXML = NULL`.

FollowUp:

After changing the onreadystatechange as below i am getting readyState=1 and status=0 and responsexml=NULL and getting only one callback

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4
    && this.status == 200) {

    if (this.responseXML != null) {
        Caption(this.video, this.responseXML);
    } else {
        throw new Error("Can't read resource");
    }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`readyState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534361%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) goes through multiple stages before the response is available. You have to wait for `readyState` to change to `4`:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {

    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        if (this.responseXML != null) {
            Caption(this.video, this.responseXML);
        } else {
            throw new Error("Can't read resource");
        }
    }

};
```

It's also best to check [`status`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534650%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (e.g., to make sure it's `200 <= status < 300` (as 2xx are the "ok" responses), although your `this.responseXML != null` is probably good enough for this use.

Comment: @BrunoLM: Thanks. Feel free to just jump in on those.

Comment: @T.JCrowder Please check the question, i have edited.

Comment: @akshay: If you're doing this loading the file from your local drive (e.g., `file://...` rather than `http://...` or `https://...`), most browsers disallow ajax calls from `file://...` resources.

Comment: I found the problem. Its with the path name. now getting readyState=4